# code to run combination of strings in parallel

Tags: c#

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Combinations<T>(this IEnumerable<T> elements, int k)
{
    return k == 0 
        ? new[] { new T[0] } 
        : elements.SelectMany((e, i) => elements
              .Skip(i + 1).Combinations(k - 1)
              .Select(c => (new[] { e }).Concat<T>(c)));
    }
```

The code currently runs combination of strings in series e.g list of a,b,c in two ways would give ab,ac,bc which is very correct. Is there a way I can modify the code to run the combination in parallel (i.e to max my cpu processor) because I intend to run combination on large volume of strings.

Comment: use `elements.AsParallel().SelectMany...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should introduce some parallelism. Note in particular the `AsParallel`.

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Combinations<T>(this IEnumerable<T> elements, int k)
{
    return k == 0 ? (IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>)new[] { new T[0] } : elements.AsParallel().SelectMany((e, i) => elements.Skip(i + 1).Combinations(k - 1).Select(c => (new[] { e }).Concat<T>(c)));
}
```

*You could also consider using `Enumerable.Empty` rather than `new T[0]`.*

Comment: the method would not compile by trying to introduce parallelism that way

Comment: There is no implicit conversion between 'T[][]' and System.Linq.ParallelQuery<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>

I still had this same error after replacing new T[0] with Enumerable.Empty

Comment: It would be excellent if you could provide timings for this method now.

Comment: please  Enigmativity can u explain further, i do not understand what you mean

Comment: He is suggesting you actually compare the speeds of your original code vs the "parallelized" version, and ensure that the new code is actually faster than the old code.

Comment: I have not been able to get the parallelized version to work, i have still not able to compile it yet

Comment: my bad, i did not rebuild the solution that why i got the compilation errors, introducing the As Parallel in the code did not introduce any form of parallelism. If one could help me with a code that can do combination of string in parallel i would be very grateful.

Comment: What make you think it `did not introduce any form of parallelism` @OsamuyimenOsagiedeDennis ?

Comment: my cpu monitor dd not spike up like it normally does anytime i am running a  parallel code, and when i set timing between series and the edited parallel method, i observed the two timings were almost the same thing.

Comment: `Parallel` doesn't always mean faster @OsamuyimenOsagiedeDennis .